# Why is .map Disappearing / Failing to Render when my React Property Changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm having a problem related to React, the context API, and rendering with a `.map` function. My functional component renders from the data *originally* passed down through a Context Provider, but when that data is updated (again, through the Context Provider), the `.map` method I'm using basically *disappears*.

Key detail: the Component successfully `console.log`s the `listings` prop (both on initial render, and on the updated render), with the data. However, *it only renders via the `.map` method when the data hits the Component the first time.*

### Expected Behavior

A user clicks a button, which pulls data and changes the value of the `listings` property, causing the Component to render new data via the `.map` method.

### Observed Behavior

The Component renders, via the `.map` method, but when a user clicks a button, causing the `listings` property to update with new data, the Component renders *nothing*.

### What this Looks Like

#### First Render

Data is consumed from a Context Provider, and the `.map` method successfully renders.

[image: First Render]

#### Second Render (after user causes the data to update)

On the right, you see that the Component (below the navbar) renders nothing, even though it `console.log`s an updated property, with data in the `.data` property.

[image: Second Render]

### Code Samples

**Feed Component**

```
export default function Feed() {

  let { listings } = useContext(BrowseContext)

  console.log(listings)

  return (
    <>
      { 
        (listings.status === 'loaded') 
      ? listings.data.map(listing => <div key={listing.seoTitle}>{listing.productTitle}</div> ) 
      : <>
          <Container style={{ marginTop: '18px' }}>
            <Skeleton animation="wave" />
            <Skeleton animation="wave" />
            <Skeleton animation="wave" />
            <Skeleton animation="wave" />
          </Container>
        </>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

** Context Provider **
*Note: The user is triggering the 'favorites' query to update the data*

```
export const BrowseContext = createContext()

const BrowseContextProvider = (props) => {

  let [listings, setListings] = useState({ status: 'loading', query: 'none', radius: 10000 })

  let { user } = useContext(AuthContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.status === 'loading' || user.status === 'loggedOut') {
        async function getTopListings() {
          let data = []
          let results = await firestore.collection('listings').orderBy('numFavorites').limit(10).get()
          results.forEach(result => data.push(result.data()))
          setListings({ status: 'loaded', data })
        }
      if (listings.status !== 'loaded') {
        getTopListings()
      }
    }
  }, [user])

  const handleQuery = async (type) => {
    switch(type) {
      case 'favorites':
        await setListings({ ...listings, status: 'loading' })
        if (!user.userDoc.favorites.length) return
        let favoriteListings = []
        user.userDoc.favorites.forEach(async favorite => {
          let get = await firestore.collection('listings').doc(favorite).get()
          let data = await get.data()
          if (typeof data !== 'undefined') favoriteListings.push(data)
        })
        await setListings({ ...listings, status: 'loaded', data: favoriteListings })
        break
      case 'top listings':
        getTopListings()
        break
      default:
        console.log(`Error in BrowseContext handleQuery: Got to default.`)
    }
  }
...
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: how is your `BrowseContextProvider` used? I've only see the `<MyContext.Provider value={}>` use cases as shown in the docs.